# How to separate brackets in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, string

I've been using the following code for the problem. I'm making a program to change the IUPAC name into structure, so i want to analyse the string entered by the user.In IUPAC name there are brackets as well. I want to extract the compound name as per the brackets. The way I have shown in the end.

I want to modify the way such that the output comes out to be like this and to be stored in an array :

> As ["(4'-cyanobiphenyl-4-yl)","5-[(4'-cyanobiphenyl-4-yl)oxy]",
>   "({5-[(4'-cyanobiphenyl-4-yl)oxy]pentyl}" .... and so on ]

And the code for splitting which i wrote is:

```
    Reg_bracket=/([^(){}\[\]]*)([(){}\[\]])/

    attr_reader :obrk, :cbrk     
    def count_level_br
        @xbrk=0
        @cbrk=0
        if  @temp1 
          @obrk+=1 if @temp1[1]=="(" || @temp1[1]=="[" ||@temp1[1]=="{"  
          @obrk-=1 if @temp1[1]==")" || @temp1[1]=="]" ||@temp1[1]=="}"
       end
       puts @obrk.to_s
    end

    def split_at_bracket(str=nil) #to split the brackets according to Regex
        if str a=str
        else a=self
        end
        a=~Reg_bracket
        if $& @temp1=[$1,$2,$']
        end
        @temp1||=[a,"",""]
      end


      def find_block
       @obrk=0 , r=""
       @temp1||=["",""]
        split_at_bracket
        r<<@temp1[0]<<@temp1[1]              
             count_level_br
       while @obrk!=0                  
          split_at_bracket(@temp1[2])
         r<<@temp1[0]<<@temp1[1]
         count_level_br
        puts r.to_s
         if @obrk==0
          puts "Level 0 has reached"
          #puts "Close brackets are #{@cbrk}"
           return r 
         end
       end #end

      end
    end #class end'
```

I ve used the regex to match the brackets. And then when it finds any bracket it gives the result of before match, after match and second after match and then keeps on doing it until it reaches to the end.

The output which I m getting right now is this.

```
1
2
1-[(
3
1-[({
4
1-[({5-[
5
1-[({5-[(
4
1-[({5-[(4'-cyanobiphenyl-4-yl)
3
1-[({5-[(4'-cyanobiphenyl-4-yl)oxy]
2
1-[({5-[(4'-cyanobiphenyl-4-yl)oxy]pentyl}
1
1-[({5-[(4'-cyanobiphenyl-4-yl)oxy]pentyl}oxy)
0
1-[({5-[(4'-cyanobiphenyl-4-yl)oxy]pentyl}oxy)carbonyl]
Level 0 has reached
testing ends'
```

Comment: can you post samples of the input you have and the output that you want

Comment: @IanKenney I've posted the output result i want in the beginning. And the Input that i give is like 1-[({5-[(4'-cyanobiphenyl-4-yl)oxy]pentyl}oxy)carbonyl] ethane 

An IUPAC name of a compound, type string.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a simple program to match the string using three different regular expressions. The first one will help separate out the parenthesis, the second will separate out the square brackets and the third will give the curly braces. Here is the following code. I hope you will be able to use it in your program effectively.

```
reg1 = /(\([a-z0-9\'\-\[\]\{\}]+.+\))/ # for parenthesis
reg2 = /(\[[a-z0-9\'\-\(\)\{\}]+.+\])/ # for square brackets
reg3 = /(\{[a-z0-9\'\-\(\)\[\]]+.+\})/ # for curly braces  

a = Array.new 
s = gets.chomp

x = reg1.match(s)
a << x.to_s
str = x.to_s.chop.reverse.chop.reverse
while x != nil do
    x = reg1.match(str)
    a << x.to_s
    str = x.to_s.chop
end

x = reg2.match(s)
a << x.to_s
str = x.to_s.chop.reverse.chop.reverse
while x != nil do
        x = reg2.match(str)
        a << x.to_s
        str = x.to_s.chop
end

x = reg3.match(s)
a << x.to_s
str = x.to_s.chop.reverse.chop.reverse
while x != nil do
        x = reg3.match(str)
        a << x.to_s
        str = x.to_s.chop
end

puts a
```

The output is a follows :

```
ruby reg_yo.rb 
4,4'{-1-[({5-[(4'-cyanobiphenyl-4-yl)oxy]pentyl}oxy)carbonyl]-2-[(4'-cyanobiphe‌​nyl-4-yl)oxy]ethylene}dihexanoic acid # input string

({5-[(4'-cyanobiphenyl-4-yl)oxy]pentyl}oxy)carbonyl]-2-[(4'-cyanobiphe‌​nyl-4-yl)
(4'-cyanobiphenyl-4-yl)oxy]pentyl}oxy)
(4'-cyanobiphenyl-4-yl)

[({5-[(4'-cyanobiphenyl-4-yl)oxy]pentyl}oxy)carbonyl]-2-[(4'-cyanobiphe‌​nyl-4-yl)oxy]
[(4'-cyanobiphenyl-4-yl)oxy]pentyl}oxy)carbonyl]
[(4'-cyanobiphenyl-4-yl)oxy]

{-1-[({5-[(4'-cyanobiphenyl-4-yl)oxy]pentyl}oxy)carbonyl]-2-[(4'-cyanobiphe‌​nyl-4-yl)oxy]ethylene}
{5-[(4'-cyanobiphenyl-4-yl)oxy]pentyl}
```

Update : I have modified the code so as to search for recursive patterns.

Comment: Hey Anup its not working, if I input this it just doesn't work. 

"4,4'{-1-[({5-[(4'-cyanobiphenyl-4-yl)oxy]pentyl}oxy)carbonyl]-2-[(4'-cyanobiphenyl-4-yl)oxy]ethylene}dihexanoic acid"

Comment: I get this --> ["(4'-cyanobiphenyl-4-yl)", "[(4'-cyanobiphenyl-4-yl)oxy]", "{5-[(4'-cyanobiphenyl-4-yl)oxy]pentyl}"].
What is your expected output?

Comment: It should be ["(4'-cyanobiphenyl-4-yl)", "[(4'-cyanobiphenyl-4-yl)oxy]", "{5-[(4'-cyanobiphenyl-4-yl)oxy]pentyl}", "({5-[(4'-cyanobiphenyl-4-yl)oxy]pentyl}oxy)", "{-1-[({5-[(4'-cyanobiphenyl-4-yl)oxy]pentyl}oxy)carbonyl]-2-[(4'-cyanobiphe‌​nyl-4-yl)oxy]ethylene}" , "4,4'{-1-[({5-[(4'-cyanobiphenyl-4-yl)oxy]pentyl}oxy)carbonyl]-2-[(4'-cyanobiphe‌​nyl-4-yl)oxy]ethylene}dihexanoic acid"] 

It should be this.

Comment: I have modified the code so as to get most of the patterns. Though, to get the correct output you will need a parser which can handle type 2 grammar. I recommend you look up parsers in ruby. [Here](https://github.com/seattlerb/ruby_parser).

Comment: I m still getting the same output not working for me :/ 

 def xyz(str=nil)

  a=Array.new
  s=self     

I just made the following change, but it no working.